# Ordenação Datatable jQuery

Tags: jquery-datatables

Estou com dois probleminhas no datatable do jQuery.

1. Ordenar colunas: a ordem alfabética de uma das colunas está ordenando erroneamente, por exemplo da coluna de tipos de conta. A conta de Energia fica antes da conta de Água, porque a palavra água tem acento na primeira letra e o plugin entende que letras com acento vem depois das sem acentos.
2. Tenho uma coluna que tem que os dados são string, mas iniciam com números (ou não), por exemplo 1º batalhão, 2º batalhão e assim por diante, ou apenas string por exemplo, infantaria, mecânica, etc. Quando clico pra ordenar por essa coluna o 10º batalhão vem logo antes do 1º batalhão e o 9º batalhão fica por último. Tentei forçar os dados dessa coluna no PHP para serem apenas int, mas aí as strings não são mostradas na tela. Como resolvo? Relacionado a esta coluna, tenho uma coluna 'hide' com os ids de cada batalhão. Se fosse possível, poderia ordenar por essa outra coluna quando clicasse na primeira. Não sei se fui claro.

Answer (score -1):

Encontrei uma solução ao modo gambiarra... mas deu certo por enquanto. Clique [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022279/jquery-datatable-title-numeric-sort) para página da solução.
Abraço.

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links)